# Function Count and Find values

Tags: excel, function, search, count, find

I use this function to count how many times these values appear:

```
=COUNTIFS(I:I;">100";I:I;"<300";A:A;"=1")
```

> result: 3

How can I find the rows from this result?

Comment: sorry but i did not understood...
can you help me with some function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to return the 2nd, third, etc row(s), you will have to use some form of array processing whether or not it will be an actual array formula. It is best to minimize the number of rows in your cell ranges and avoid full column references altogether.

[image: Firs, second, third rows from multiple criteria]

The formula in L3 is,

```
=IF(ROW(1:1)<=COUNTIFS(I:I; ">100";I:I; "<300";A:A; 1); SMALL(INDEX(ROW($1:$999)+((I$1:I$999<=100)+(I$1:I$999>=300)+(A$1:A$999<>1))*1E+99;;);ROW(1:1)); "")
```

Fill down as necessary to catch all rows that are returned from the match(es) to the multiple criteria.

To return the actual value of the cell(s), use the long integer value (aka *row number*) returned by the [SMALL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-4050a82e-659a-4ef6-a970-c963a6f69c29) with an [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) referencing column I:I.

```
=IF(ROW(1:1)<=COUNTIFS(I:I; ">100";I:I; "<300";A:A; 1); INDEX(I:I; SMALL(INDEX(ROW($1:$999)+((I$1:I$999<=100)+(I$1:I$999>=300)+(A$1:A$999<>1))*1E+99;;); ROW(1:1))); "")
```

I used a search and replace to change my comma list separators to your semi-colons and I *think* I got it right but cannot check short of reversing my system's regional settings.

Comment: Hi Jeeped, one more question please, in that formula you gave me, what should i change to return the value inside the celula instead of row number.

Comment: @MarcosPintodeSousa - Had a feeling that might come up :). Please see my edit to the post above.